# My loaded children are being lost when using automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am mapping my entity object with Automapper and as you will see in the comments below my Collection of groups gets lost after mapping.

```
 public partial class WebUser
{
    public WebUser()
    {
        this.WebUserGroups = new HashSet<WebUserGroup>();
    }

    public int UserKey { get; set; }
    //stuff

    public virtual ICollection<WebUserGroup> WebUserGroups { get; set; }
}

public void Edit(WebUser user)
    {
        //Has collection of WebUserGroups populated
        var userToBeEdited = GetUserBy(user.UserKey);
        var updatedWebUser = Mapper.Map(user, userToBeEdited);
        //Lost after mapping
        _context.Entry(updatedWebUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

public WebUser GetUserBy(int userKey)
{
    return (from webUser in _context.WebUsers
        join webUserGroup in _context.WebUserGroups on webUser.UserKey equals webUserGroup.UserKey
        select webUser).FirstOrDefault();
}

Mapper.CreateMap<WebUser, WebUser>()
            .ForSourceMember(dest => dest.UserKey, src => src.Ignore())
            .ForSourceMember(dest => dest.WebUserGroups, src => src.Ignore());
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `.ForMember` instead of `.ForSourceMember`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<WebUser, WebUser>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UserKey, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.WebUserGroups, opt => opt.Ignore());
```